# MessageBox not displaying on Windows XP

Tags: winapi, messagebox

I have two machines: my dev machine has Windows Server 2008 R2 on it, along with Visual Studio 2008. I'm compiling my applciation on there. My other machine is the target machine and it runs Windows XP.

The problem is that I have a `MessageBox` call that works on the dev machine but not on the target machine.

I've commented out everything in `WinMain` so that it is now only this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Your application is already running!", "Application Notification", MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

On the dev machine the message box pops up fine (with no sound), on the XP machine everything else is fine, except that instead of the popup box I just hear the "ba-ding" popup sound.

What small setting in the bowels of MSVC++ do I need to change to get this to work on XP?

The character set I'm using is "Not Set". I'm not sure if that does anything, but I tried changing it to multibyte with no dice.

Comment: This code works for me in both XP, Vista and 7. (Though i am using Visual Studio 2010 - but this shouldn't really make a difference). Anyway, I have a feeling you may need to adjust some of your compiler and/or linker settings. Have you tried starting a new visual studio project using only the code you posted and leaving all the default compiler and linker options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the beep-instead-of-a-window thing when there is a misconfigured manifest resource/external appname.exe.manifest so if your using one, try disabling it.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, and after some searching I found this solution on the web: call InitCommonControls() before you display the MessageBox. This solved the problem for me.

Like Alex K. noticed, this is caused by a manifest. If you load version 6 of ComCtl32.dll by specifying that in the manifest, you need to call InitCommonControls() on Windows XP before you can use the controls, or else they won't be loaded, and that's why you can't see the MessageBox (though you can hear it).

Answer (score 0):

This is about as basic as it can get and should work on any windows system. You could check the return value of MessageBox, if it is 0, call GetLastError()